# Why can't I use interpolation in Angular 2 when binding to my child component

Tags: angular, interpolation

If I want to bind the 'src' of an 'image' tag I can do either of

```
<img src='{{heroImageUrl}}'>
```

or

```
<img [src]='heroImageUrl'>
```

But if I have a child component using the selector , I can do

```
<app-child [hero]='myHero'></app-child1>
```

but not

```
<app-child hero={{myHero}}></app-child1>
```

The fact that I don't quite understand why not mean's I guess I'm not quite grokking the way interpolation is working in Angular 2.

Can you explain why I can do one (with the image tag) and not the other?

Answer (score 3):

I assume `myHero` is an object. `{{}}` is for string interpolation, this means the result is always a string. Your `myHero` will probably be passed as `'[object Object]'`.

```ts
[hero]="myHero"
```

passes `myHero` as object and will be received by `<app-child>` unaltered.

In the former example with the `src` property it doesn't matter because it's a string anyway.

Comment: It does look like this is the case - and that makes sense.
I was mis-interpreting the discussion at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#interpolation
where they say
"There is no technical reason to prefer one form to the other. We lean toward readability, which tends to favor interpolation."
Which perhaps needs the addition of "if you're dealing with strings" for the likes of me.

Comment: I think this is worth a bug report in https://github.com/angular/angular.io

Answer (score 1):

You need to put quotation :

```
<app-child hero="{{myHero}}"></app-child1>
```

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/U95P1DL2wTdfpQgyVkfA?p=preview)

To be exact :

More generally, the material between the braces is a template expression that Angular first evaluates and then converts to a string.

**So, it means you cannot pass a class or function through interpolation to the other side , otherwise you'll get the stringified version.**

Comment: I think that is only true if the item is a string - but in my example 'myHero' is an object and not a string.
If you change your plunkr to use a class *car* with a *name* property then it doesn't work, with or without quotes.

Comment: @Maxxx , updated my plunker , it uses an object and it works.

Comment: I also created a plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/9wPF0y?p=preview using an angular class, and it doesn't work; I will compare the two to see what is the difference (though I suspect it is as simple as pointed out by Günter - your array interpolates into a string, mine does not?)

Comment: @Maxxx , dude , it's very easy , I don't know what are you looking for, you're Hero is a Class , it'll be stringified when you interpolate it and thus you can't access to it's properties inside your myChild component.

Comment: dude, everything is very easy when you know it! Until then, it requires questioning and experimentation!
I still have yet to find anywhere in the Angular docs where it specifies that foo = {{bar}} stringifies and 
[foo] = 'bar' doesn't.